# Oracle SQL ignores page item in a criteria, when it is null

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-5

When my page loads the page item :P2136_LEAVE_TYPE is null.
i have this query

```
WITH Emp_Leaves AS
    (select ID,
           EMPLOYEE_ID,
           LEAVE_YEAR,
           LEAVE_TYPE,
           LEAVE_DAYS,
           REMAINING_DAYS,
           CLOSED
    from LEAVES_PERSONEL
    where "EMPLOYEE_ID" = :P2136_EMPLOYEE_ID
    and REMAINING_DAYS > 0 and  CLOSED = 0
    order by LEAVE_YEAR, LEAVE_TYPE)

select ID,
           EMPLOYEE_ID,
           LEAVE_YEAR,
           LEAVE_TYPE,
           LEAVE_DAYS,
           REMAINING_DAYS,
           CLOSED
  FROM Emp_Leaves;
```

i want when the user change the value in my page item :P2136_LEAVE_TYPE and its not null to use it as a criteria in my query like this:

```
WITH Emp_Leaves AS
        (select ID,
               EMPLOYEE_ID,
               LEAVE_YEAR,
               LEAVE_TYPE,
               LEAVE_DAYS,
               REMAINING_DAYS,
               CLOSED
        from LEAVES_PERSONEL
        where "EMPLOYEE_ID" = :P2136_EMPLOYEE_ID
        **and LEAVE_TYPE = :P2136_LEAVE_TYPE**
        and REMAINING_DAYS > 0 and  CLOSED = 0
        order by LEAVE_YEAR, LEAVE_TYPE)
    
    select ID,
               EMPLOYEE_ID,
               LEAVE_YEAR,
               LEAVE_TYPE,
               LEAVE_DAYS,
               REMAINING_DAYS,
               CLOSED
      FROM Emp_Leaves;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also test for NULL, so that the condition is true if one of the cobditions is true

```
WITH Emp_Leaves AS
    (select ID,
           EMPLOYEE_ID,
           LEAVE_YEAR,
           LEAVE_TYPE,
           LEAVE_DAYS,
           REMAINING_DAYS,
           CLOSED
    from LEAVES_PERSONEL
    where "EMPLOYEE_ID" = :P2136_EMPLOYEE_ID
    and (LEAVE_TYPE = :P2136_LEAVE_TYPE* OR LEAVE_TYPE IS NULL)
    and REMAINING_DAYS > 0 and  CLOSED = 0
    order by LEAVE_YEAR, LEAVE_TYPE)

select ID,
           EMPLOYEE_ID,
           LEAVE_YEAR,
           LEAVE_TYPE,
           LEAVE_DAYS,
           REMAINING_DAYS,
           CLOSED
  FROM Emp_Leaves;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the bind value `IS NULL`:

```sql
select ID,
       EMPLOYEE_ID,
       LEAVE_YEAR,
       LEAVE_TYPE,
       LEAVE_DAYS,
       REMAINING_DAYS,
       CLOSED
from   LEAVES_PERSONEL
where  EMPLOYEE_ID = :P2136_EMPLOYEE_ID
and    REMAINING_DAYS > 0
and    CLOSED = 0
and    (LEAVE_TYPE = :P2136_LEAVE_TYPE OR :P2136_LEAVE_TYPE IS NULL)
order by LEAVE_YEAR, LEAVE_TYPE
```

*Note: You do not need the sub-query factoring (`WITH`) clause or the double-quotes around an upper-case identifier.*